# How to send a variable size of input from Pig Latin to User Defined Function

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I am using a simple UDF in Pig Latin / MapReduce. the Pig Latin query is:

```
REGISTER \PigStringOperations.jar
sensitive = LOAD '/mdsba/sample2.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (AGE:int,EDU:chararray,SEX:chararray,SALARY:chararray);
BV= group  sensitive by (EDU,SEX) ; 
BVA= foreach BV generate sensitive.AGE as AGE;
anon = FOREACH BVA  GENERATE PigStringOperations.StringSplit(sensitive.AGE);
DUMP anon;
```

The UDF is a simple java program
as shown below

```
public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException
  String data = (String)input.get(0);
if (data.contains(" "))
{
  this.data2 = data.split(" ");
  return this.data2[0].toString();
}
return data;}}
```

This is taken from the adult database [Adult database sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44vVT.png)
The AGE output from grouping (EDU,SEX) varies from one tuple to another, as shown below

```
AGE(12,10,35,20)
AGE(4,56,10)
AGE(70)
```

Each time I run the program I recieve the following error:

```
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias anon. Backend error : org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (,EDU,SEX,SALARY), 2nd :(39,Bachelors,Male,<=50K)
```

Comment: What are you to trying to achieve? What should be the output?

Comment: It is a simple program that calculates the interval age for the same SEX and EDU. So i First grouped the SEX, EDU for different ages, then I need the Java of UDF to complete the AGE calculations. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping the data the sensitive.AGE will be a bag! Consider this when you plan your UDF.
If you would do DESCRIBE on your projections, like:

```
DESCRIBE BVA;
```

That would help you to understand the data structure and plan your processing accordingly.

Comment: But the bag is a group of records for the same attribute or column. In my case I am not sure if this also considered as a bag.

Comment: I suggest to do a DESCRIBE on all your projections and check the schema. And BVA does not contains sensitive.AGE as you renamed that bag to AGE. You'll see this also if you do the describe.